# How to set Out parameter in method in same class

Tags: c#

```
  Main()
   {
    bool flag = false;
    ClassA obj = new ClassA(out flag);

    if(flag==true)
    {
        //do smething
    }
}

ClassA
{
    ClassA(out bool flag)
    {
       flag = false;      
    }
    private void SomeClickEvent()
    {
         flag = true;
    }
}
```

I am passing bool value to constructor. Need to set value in `SomeClickMethod()` same value will be return as out parameter how can i do?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. `SomeClickMethod` is private and not being called.

Comment: The code above simply doesn't make sense, please reword it to be more clear.

Comment: How? can any example

Comment: i have to set out parameter value in method how can i do

Comment: `void SomeClickMethod(out bool flag) { .. }` ?

Comment: Your method is private - please show an example of how it would be called **from within ClassA**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value types are passed by value. If you want to keep a reference around in your class and modify it in another method and see the changes reflected to the outside, either expose a property or introduce a container class, which will be passed by reference.

So either expose a property:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool SomeValue { get; }

    public Foo(bool someValue)
    {
        SomeValue = someValue;
    }

    public void Foo2()
    {
        SomeValue = true;
    }
}
```

Where you call it like this:

```
bool flag = false;
var obj = new Foo(flag);
// ...
flag = obj.SomeValue;
```

Or create a container to hold the value:

```
public class BoolContainer
{
    public bool SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    private BoolContainer _boolContainer;

    public Foo(BoolContainer boolContainer)
    {
        _boolContainer = boolContainer;
    }

    public void Foo2()
    {
        _boolContainer.SomeValue = true;
    }
}
```

Where you call it like this:

```
var boolContainer = new BoolContainer();
var obj = new Foo(boolContainer);
// ...
bool flag = boolContainer.SomeValue;
```

Now the caller can access `boolContainer.SomeValue` to inspect (or alter) the value.

Comment: I somehow prefer the second example, given that the OP's implementation of Foo2 is private, but I can't explain why I prefer that one. Care to share your thoughts?

Comment: @rene I think it really depends on what the intended purpose is of the "flag".

Answer (score 1):

While you can return references in newer versions of C#, you cannot store them. A field in a class cannot be a reference. You have several options to work around this problem - turn the `flag` variable into the class' field, or pass a setter lambda to the constructor:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public bool flag{get; private set;}

    private void SomeClickMethod()
    {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class ClassA
{
    readonly Action<bool> setter;

    public ClassA(Action<bool> setter)
    {
        this.setter = setter;
        setter(false);
    }

    private void SomeClickMethod()
    {
        setter(true);
    }
}

bool flag = false;
ClassA obj = new ClassA(b => flag = b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just mean how to store and return a value (that's what I understand from your code):

```
ClassA
{
    bool flag1;
    ClassA(bool flag)
    {
       flag1 = flag;      
    }
    public bool SomeClickEvent()
    {
         return flag1;
    }
}
```

And use it so:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA(true);
bool b = a.SomeClickEvent();//returns true.
```

Comment: @rene Thanks! I missed fixing that part.